# Auto optimisation of variables in python

Tags: python, variables, optimization, recursion, filtering

Say I have some data to describe a signal:

```
xdata = []
ydata = []
```

The data is noisy so I wish to apply a filter of some kind. Say that filter has some variables `a and b` that can be altered.

```
somefilteringfunction(xdata,ydata,a,b)
```

Assuming I can find some way to find an error based on the average of the filtered signal deviation from the measured points. Is there a way to have the program loop back on itself to find better and better estimates for a and b?

Use initial values of a and b, run through filter, computer error

Try some other values of a and b, filter, error

... etc.

Is there a nice way in python to find these two variables? Or even three?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Without some specific information about what data you have, what your goal is, what the filtering does, etc, I think it will be hard to answer.

Comment: There is no builtin way, but you can implement the algorithm you just described.

Comment: Following up from @BrenBarn's comment, the algorithm you described is called gradient descent (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent). You only need to estimate the gradient, for example using difference quotients (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_quotient)

Comment: You can fit the xdata and ydata with your filtering function using scipy.optimize.curve_fit and find the best fitting parameters a and b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use one of the many [fitting routines](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/FittingData) that Python offers.

Say for example you can use `curve_fit` from `scipy.optimize` to find the best fitting parameters for your `a and b`. **A bare basic example of how to do it is [here in this website!](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=5215)**

You need to give in some initial parameters as mentioned in the above website and Python will iterate over it to find the best fitting values for your data.